# Software to use PS3 controller on PC

Tags: pc, ps3, motioninjoy-ds3tool

So, i used to have motioninjoy to simulate my ps3 controller on my PC.(Yes, that girl on tik tok with the overwatch song wasn't wrong, so she'll be able to play it)

I had a old version, that worked even with the motioninjoy page replaced by some chinese ads and fake facebook. But now, when i try to install the drivers of the controller, there are some errors, i guess the drivers packages are missing. So, do you guys know any software that i can use to simulate my controller instead of motioninjoy?

Answer (score 1):

I am using ScpToolkit just fine. Sometimes it has a few hickups when the controller disconnects from the PC, but besides that, everything is fine.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYyqMcxyIjk) seems to include everything needed for the setup